# Select longest streak in days from mysql database?

Tags: php, mysql, date

First off, I have found quite a few similar questions on both Google and Stackoverflow but I can't seem to grasp how to do this correctly.

I have a table that looks like this:

```
    id      ms_date
    ------------------
    1     2018-11-18
    2     2018-11-18
    3     2018-11-20
    4     2018-11-22
    5     2018-11-25
    6     2018-11-26
    7     2018-11-26
    8     2018-11-27
    9     2018-11-28
   10     2018-11-29
```

What i need to do is to get the longest streak in `Days` from that table.

So in the above example, the longest streak is `4 days`.

I found this: https://dzone.com/articles/how-to-find-the-longest-consecutive-series-of-even

and it explains what he's trying to do which is SIMILAR to what I am trying to achieve but then it is so badly explained/written that I cannot make sense of it.

I also need to find the GAP between those dates and start counting the streak again. So again in the example above, because there's a gap between the dates, the `Current Streak` should be `3 Days`.

I've tried to used the code from the link above but that is based on SQL and also it has some strange `WITH` words in  the code which doesn't make sense at all.

Is there an easy way to achieve this using PHP and Mysql ?

Could someone please advice on this issue?

Thanks in advance.

**EDIT:**

I can't seem to find the software version in my PHPMYADMIN but this is what i can see under the Database server section:

```
Server: Localhost via UNIX socket
Server type: MariaDB
Server connection: SSL is not being used Documentation
Server version: 10.0.37-MariaDB-0+deb8u1 - (Debian)
Protocol version: 10
User: freemind@localhost
Server charset: UTF-8 Unicode (utf8)
```

**Second EDIT:**

Tried the following based on the below answer and I get nothing at all:

```
$sql_COUNT = "SELECT COUNT(*) max_streak 
  FROM 
     ( SELECT x.*
            , CASE WHEN @prev = val - 1 THEN @i:=@i ELSE @i:=@i+1 END i
            , @prev:=val  
         FROM 
            ( SELECT DISTINCT ms_date FROM MY_TABLE ) x
         JOIN 
            ( SELECT @prev:=null,@i:=0 ) vars 
        ORDER 
           BY ms_date
     ) a 
 GROUP 
    BY i 
 ORDER 
    BY max_streak DESC LIMIT 1";
$query_COUNT = mysqli_query($db_conx, $sql_COUNT);
$productCount_COUNT = mysqli_num_rows($query_COUNT); // count the output amount

echo $productCount_COUNT;
```

**Third Edit:**

The following code echo's `1` on my page BUT based on what I have in MYSQL database, it should echo `4`:

```
$sql_COUNT = "SELECT COUNT(*) AS max_streak 
  FROM 
     ( SELECT x.*
            , CASE WHEN @prev = ms_date - 1 THEN @i:=@i ELSE @i:=@i+1 END i
            , @prev:=ms_date  
         FROM 
            ( SELECT DISTINCT ms_date FROM MY_TABLE ) x
         JOIN 
            ( SELECT @prev:=null,@i:=0 ) vars 
        ORDER 
           BY ms_date
     ) a 
 GROUP 
    BY i 
 ORDER 
    BY max_streak DESC LIMIT 1";
$query_COUNT = mysqli_query($db_conx, $sql_COUNT);

$productCount_COUNT = mysqli_num_rows($query_COUNT); // count the output amount

echo $productCount_COUNT;
```

**Fourth EDIT:**

I'm not sure if the answers below was tested but it doesn't work for me.

i tried the folowings and even though I get no errors, I only see a blank page which means the code is not working:

```
$sql_COUNT = "SELECT COUNT(*) max_streak 
  FROM 
     ( SELECT x.*
            , CASE WHEN @prev = ms_date - INTERVAL 1 DAY THEN @i:=@i ELSE @i:=@i+1 END i
            , @prev:=ms_date  
         FROM 
            ( SELECT DISTINCT ms_date FROM MY_TABLE ORDER BY ms_date ) x
         JOIN 
            ( SELECT @prev:=null,@i:=0 ) vars 
     ) a 
 GROUP 
    BY i 
 ORDER 
    BY max_streak DESC";
$query_COUNT = mysqli_query($db_conx, $sql_COUNT);

$count = mysqli_fetch_array($query_COUNT);
echo $count[0];
```

Comment: Comments are not for extended discussion; this conversation has been [moved to chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/183967/discussion-on-question-by-james-juanjie-select-longest-streak-in-days-from-mysql).

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Consider the following...

```
DROP TABLE IF EXISTS my_table;

CREATE TABLE my_table
(id SERIAL PRIMARY KEY
,val INT NOT NULL
);

INSERT INTO my_table VALUES
(1   , 11),
(2   , 11),
(3   , 12),
(4   , 13),
(5   , 14),
(6   , 17),
(7   , 18),
(8   , 20),
(9   , 21),
(10  , 22);

SELECT COUNT(*) max_streak 
  FROM 
     ( SELECT x.*
            , CASE WHEN @prev = val - 1 THEN @i:=@i ELSE @i:=@i+1 END i
            , @prev:=val  
         FROM 
            ( SELECT DISTINCT val FROM my_table ) x
         JOIN 
            ( SELECT @prev:=null,@i:=0 ) vars 
        ORDER 
           BY val
     ) a 
 GROUP 
    BY i 
 ORDER 
    BY max_streak DESC LIMIT 1;
+------------+
| max_streak |
+------------+
|          4 |
+------------+
1 row in set (0.01 sec)
```

EDIT:

If you're using dates, then the logic is the same, but you just have to substitute a bit of date arithmetic...

```
DROP TABLE IF EXISTS my_table;

CREATE TABLE my_table
(id SERIAL PRIMARY KEY
,val DATE NOT NULL
);

INSERT INTO my_table VALUES
(1   , '2018-11-11'),
(2   , '2018-11-11'),
(3   , '2018-11-12'),
(4   , '2018-11-13'),
(5   , '2018-11-14'),
(6   , '2018-11-17'),
(7   , '2018-11-18'),
(8   , '2018-11-20'),
(9   , '2018-11-21'),
(10  , '2018-11-22');

SELECT COUNT(*) max_streak 
  FROM 
     ( SELECT x.*
            , CASE WHEN @prev = val - INTERVAL 1 DAY THEN @i:=@i ELSE @i:=@i+1 END i
            , @prev:=val  
         FROM 
            ( SELECT DISTINCT val FROM my_table ) x
         JOIN 
            ( SELECT @prev:=null,@i:=0 ) vars 
        ORDER 
           BY val
     ) a 
 GROUP 
    BY i 
 ORDER 
    BY max_streak DESC LIMIT 1;
+------------+
| max_streak |
+------------+
|          4 |
+------------+
```

Purists would argue (correctly) that I'm using @variable assignments in an incorrect manner - but it's just a bad habit I picked up. That said, I *think* a correct assignment method is as follows, but no doubt someone will let me know if I'm mistaken...

```
SELECT COUNT(*) max_streak 
  FROM 
     ( SELECT x.*
            , CASE WHEN @prev = val - INTERVAL 1 DAY THEN @i:=@i ELSE @i:=@i+1 END i
            , @prev:=val  
         FROM 
            ( SELECT DISTINCT val FROM my_table ORDER BY val ) x
         JOIN 
            ( SELECT @prev:=null,@i:=0 ) vars 
     ) a 
 GROUP 
    BY i 
 ORDER 
    BY max_streak DESC LIMIT 1;
```

If you want to bundle this up inside some PHP, I guess it might look like this (although it should be obvious from what follows that application code is not really my forte)...

```
<?php

require('path/to/connection/stateme.nts');

$query = "
SELECT COUNT(*) max_streak
  FROM
     ( SELECT x.*
            , CASE WHEN @prev = val - INTERVAL 1 DAY THEN @i:=@i ELSE @i:=@i+1 END i
            , @prev:=val
         FROM
            ( SELECT DISTINCT val FROM MY_TABLE ORDER BY val ) x
         JOIN
            ( SELECT @prev:=null,@i:=0 ) vars
     ) a
 GROUP
    BY i
 ORDER
    BY max_streak DESC
 LIMIT 1;
";

$result = mysqli_query($conn, $query) or die(mysqli_error($conn));

$row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($result);

print_r($row);

?>

-- outputs

Array ( [max_streak] => 4 )
```

Comment: sorry I'm easily confused but where is the DATE in your example?

Comment: You'd have to change where it calculates with "val" to calculate with dates.

Comment: done that but not working. I get this error: You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MariaDB server version for the right syntax to use near 'max_streak FROM ( SELECT x.* , CASE WHEN @prev = val - 1 TH' at line 1

Comment: @Carmen Well, it wasn't a dumb question 14 months ago

Comment: @strawberry Is there a way to get the start of the streak of the streak as well?

Comment: @MikelG While this solution was valid back in 2018, using variables in this way is discouraged now, so I would look to use a more modern method. I suggest you upgrade to 8.0+, if  you can, and ask a new question to suit.

Comment: Funny, I thought I was on 5 and just checked my environment. I'm already on 8. I must have upgraded at some point and simply don't remember doing so. What functions in MySQL 8 should I be looking at to achieve this?